# check child check box by parent check box in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I am trying to check child check box by parent check box in Jquery. But code work properly for first time next its stop working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#append").delegate("#p0", "click", function () {
        if (this.checked == true) {
            $("#submenu0 input").attr('checked', true);
        } else {
            $("#submenu0 input").attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="append" name="append" style="background-color: white;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="p0" value="Administrative Boundary">
    <div id="submenu0" class="a" style=" margin-left: 29px ">
        <input type="checkbox" id="pc00" value="KBJNL:district_boundary_2011" checked="checked">District Boundary 2011
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `checked` status of the clicked checkbox, to update the other checkboxes.

See comments inline.

```
// Use change event, and on to bind events, delegate calls on inside
$("#append").on("change", "#p0", function() {
    $("#submenu0 :checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    // if this checkbox is checked then check all the checkboxes inside #submenu0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** in jquery for event delegation and also use `prop()` instead of `attr()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#append").on("change","#p0", function() {
        $("#submenu0 input").prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/76n4jdLx/4/)**